# Creating an efficient way to build a related articles feature with php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

First, let me begin by saying that I have done a lot of research on this topic and have already invested a lot of time into a workable solution.  With that said, I'm running into some issues that I can't seem to overcome and am therefore seeking some guidance in the right direction.

Little backstory: I write/maintain the php/mysql for a website.  We are basically a gaming site that posts articles, reviews, videos, etc.

**Question:** I have a mysql database that stores all of the website's content.  There are basically 4 fields in this database from which I pull words, that I would then like to match to all other articles in the database and determine the top 3 related articles so that they can be displayed. Most efficient and best way to accomplish this?

**Here's what I've done so far:**

In the CMS I have designed, I have essentially designed a "bag-of-words" type system.  The program goes through all the articles (there are about 4,000) and breaks down every word into a separate database. In this separate database the word, word count in article, tf*idf (more on this later), and article id (x-ref to content database) are stored.  So, a word can be in this database more than once, but not more than once for one article.  After processing this (which takes about 4 minutes) there are close to 700,000 entries in this new database.

Then, I have another program that goes through this new word database and parses its [tf*idf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf).  Going through the entire list of 700,000 entries takes this program about 15 minutes.

Now, this is the part that I'm stuck at.  I'm working on the frontend part of this to actually make the system usable.  The frontend part does a query of the database for the current article being viewed (article_id) and pulls the top 20 words sorted by their tf*idf.  Then, I pull these words and query them against other articles containing the words and have an array that stores the articles being compared and the number of times they match up.  Then, sort the array and pull the top 3 articles with the highest number of comparisons.

This last part works fine and dandy and I actually get pretty good comparisons using a mix between tf*idf and bag-of-words.  The problem is that for the frontend part to happen, it takes anywhere from 30-45 seconds.  Obviously this is not feasible... it has to be done in a fraction of a second and this is where I'm running into my issue.

I know this was really long, and I apologize for that.  I'm basically looking for some help cleaning this idea up, some place I went wrong, different approach.  I'm open to all suggestions and would be happy to provide any more information if it would make any of this clearer.  Thanks for your time!

Per request, table schema and front end code...

```
--
-- Table structure for table `bagofwords`
--
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bagofwords` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `article_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `article_total_word_count` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `word` text NOT NULL,
  `count` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tfidf` float NOT NULL,
  KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=660930 ;


public function related_articles($article_id, $count = 3) {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `bagofwords` WHERE `article_id` = '$article_id' ORDER BY `tfidf` DESC LIMIT 20";
        $result = $this->db->query($query);
        $num_rows = $this->db->num_rows($result);

        $articles_list = array();
        for ($i=0; $i<$num_rows; $i++) {
            $word = $this->db->fetch_field($result, 'word', $i);

            $query_word = "SELECT `article_id` FROM `bagofwords` WHERE `word` = '$word' AND `article_id` != '$article_id' ORDER BY `tfidf` DESC";
            $result_word = $this->db->query($query_word);
            $result_num_rows = $this->db->num_rows($result_word);
            for ($x=0; $x<$result_num_rows; $x++) {
                $article_id_word = $this->db->fetch_field($result_word, 'article_id', $x);
                if (isset($articles_list["$article_id_word"])) $articles_list["$article_id_word"]++;
                else $articles_list["$article_id_word"] = 1;
            }
        }

        array_flip($articles_list);
        asort($articles_list);
        return $articles_list;

    }
```

Ok, this is pretty much the frontend code part, as of right now it returns the entire array and var_dumps on the frontend just to see what kinda data I'm getting.  But ya, there has gotta be a better way to write all of this in a single mySQL statement using nested stuff or temp tables.  I can't figure it out!

Comment: Can't you move this into a cronjob that re-indexes everything every night or something therefore effectively creating a cache?

Comment: Are you asking to optimize your SQL, or for architectural ideas? If the former, can you please post schema and queries?

Comment: This is an impressive amount of work, but it looks like you're re-implementing Solr.  Is there a reason you can't use a dedicated search server?  A lot of smart people put a lot of work in to build and test it, and it can generate lists of related documents for you.

Comment: Why not just `DELETE` all the low tt*idf words?
It should leave you with only 20% of the current amount of words.

Comment: @NevilleK - Well, possibly optimizing the SQL for the frontend would help.  Right now I'm running a lot of queries on the front end, and I would imagine that is what is taking so long.  It queries once to pull the list of words, then queries each word individually and then saves each article_id into an array from each query.  So I'm basically doing 21 queries on a database with 700,000 entries.  If there is a way to some how run a query that: pulls top 20 words for article, adds up number of times they appear in other articles and saves the number of times unique to each article_id.

Comment: @Treffynnon - Caching is something else I thought about, but ultimately have decided that what I'm doing could probably be made more efficient.  I'm not worried about how long it takes the backend stuff to happen and would be willing to make it take even longer if it meant the frontend stuff running faster.

Comment: If you want help optimizing the SQL, you'll need to post schema and queries for us to poke around with

Comment: @user1235881 I completely understand your hesitation, but I think you'll find it saves you a lot of time.  It sounds perfect for your needs, and you could move on to building functionality specific to your site.  It's also open source, so you're really just looking at having the memory to run it somewhere.

Comment: @menacingly Just looked into this and Solr can't be implemented on Dreamhost =/  I'd have to move hosts.

Comment: @NevilleK - Updated article with table schema and code on frontend.

Comment: @OfirBaruch - An interesting idea... The queries might run faster if mySQL didn't have to run 21 queries on such a large database.

Comment: Do you have any indices on the table?

Comment: @NevilleK I'm not sure what that means

Comment: @NevilleK I just figured out what you meant tho... I indexed all of the fields that I would possibly need to search by: article_id, word (changed to varchar(200)), and tfidf.  It vastly improved the front end parse time.  The entire page, with this code + the rest of the website, is now parsing in normal time (0.01-0.1 seconds)! Thank you!!

Comment: @NevilleK Not sure how to mark your comment as the answer...

Comment: Is there an index on the column "word"? Also, see my answer below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious thing is to run this query as a self-join. I'd need to test on production volumes to optimize it, but something like:

```
select word, count(*) as article_count
from   bagofwords article, 
       bagofwords relations
where  article.article_id = '$article_id'
and    article.word       = relation.word
group by word
order by article.tfidf, article_count

limit 20
```

You also want an index on the colum "word":

```
create index word on bagofwords(word)
```

Comment: Thanks for all the help, I'm still learning a lot about mysql syntax outside of basic stuff... I'll try this out right now and let you know how it works out

Comment: Ok, well I had to slightly modify your code to get it to work.  This is what I ended up with:------select relations.word, relations.article_id, relations.tfidf
from   bagofwords article, bagofwords relations
where  article.article_id = '3415'
and    (relations.word = article.word AND relations.article_id != article.article_id)
order by relations.tfidf desc
limit 20----Unfortunately, that has a few problems because it bases article relation solely on highest tf*idf instead of factoring in tf*idf and highest article count which I can't seem to figure how to add up w/o pulling the data into php.

Comment: The article_id ='3415' was just me testing the code in phpmyadmin

Comment: I've added a way of ordering by the number of articles. However, if adding the index on "word" has made it fast enough, I'd leave it for now...

Comment: I tried your updated code but am getting syntax errors in regards to "group by word limit 20".  And ya, it seems that doing simple queries after indexing the columns I'm searching is faster than the complex queries so far.

Comment: With your edited code above modified a tiny bit, the query is taking ~ 5 seconds to execute.  Whereas just pulling the data into php and parsing it there takes a fraction of a second.  So, I'm just gonna stick with the code I have.  But thank you very much for opening my eyes to table indices... I didn't really know what they did until you mentioned it.  Thanks!